# How to store last part of string?

Tags: ios4

I have a string as  http://www.google.co.uk/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif.
I need to save only the partly_cloudy.gif .How do i select obly that part of string?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that it represents a path then you can call the [`lastPathComponent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lastPathComponent) method on it.

#### Usage

```
NSString * link = @"http://www.google.co.uk/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif";
NSLog(@"%@", [link lastPathComponent]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSString function `componentsSeparatedByString`. For example, `NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com/1/2/3/test.gif"; NSArray *components = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];` would give you an NSArray of all strings in between a '/' character.

NSString reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html